# while() different outputs; same variable

Tags: c++, while-loop

If possible, I want to know **how does while** in C++ **interprets** this two different codes.

The difference between the two of them is that the first while is loaded from the previous var which was already given a value and the second code the value of the variable is given when doing the while.

The code below is a part of a very simple "printing all files in a directory" programme done with

1st. **Value is given when doing the while**. Returns all files as intended

```
    ent = readdir(directory);
    if(ent == NULL){
        cout << "Cannot read directory!";
    }else{
        while((ent = readdir (directory)) != NULL){
        cout << ent->d_name; //this one is the one which works fine; value is given when doing the while
        }
    }
```

2n. **Value is given to the variable before doing the while**. Return an infinite bucle with the first value of the while.

```
        ent = readdir(directory);
        if(ent == NULL){
            cout << "Cannot read directory!";
        }else{
            while((ent) != NULL){
            cout << ent->d_name; //this one returns an infinite bucle of only the first value of the while
            }
        }
```

How is C++ interpreting them?

Comment: In the second case, `ent` will always be the result of `readdir(directory)`, if it's not `NULL`, it's an infinite loop.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Unless ent happens to have an overloaded -> operator that does something really really weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not re-evaluating `ent` in the second version on each iteration. So its value will never change and thus if you enter the loop once you will always stay inside.

On the contrary in the first version the code `while((ent = readdir (directory)) != NULL)` will assign a new value to `ent` on each iteration and may exit the loop once `ent`(or actually `readdir(directory)` turns out to be NULL.

Answer (score 4):

You seriously need to re-read that tutorial...

***The condition of the `while()` statement is evaluated and checked before each iteration.***

So this:

```
while ((ent = readdir(directory)) != NULL)
```

will call `readdir()` upon every iteration, while the other one won't. From this point, you can do the logic yourself, you'll see why it works the way it does.

Comment: To newer beginners, some of those words may seem confusing. A beginner might just read that as, "*before each iteration 'ent' is compared to NULL*", whereas more experienced programmers like the rest of us would understand more clearly what 'evaluated' means, and the consequences of it being re-evaluated every iteration. It's a easy mistake for a beginner to make when reading it, especially with all the programmer-inspeak. (condition, statement, evaluated, iteration... in one sentence) =)
Upvoted your post for the correct answer though.

Comment: @JaminGrey No. What I wrote cannot be interpreted that way. "The condition of the `while()` statement" is the condition of the `while()` statement, not the second part of it.

Comment: It fully can be *mistakenly* interpreted that way, *to someone new to the terminology*, which was my only point. I'm talking about the wording of "**The condition of the while() statement is evaluated and checked before each iteration.**", not the wording of your post. (I thought you were quoting directly from the tutorial the OP read)

Answer (score 0):

In the first one, the ent=readdir(directory) causes it to get the next directory, eventually becoming null, and ending the while loop. Note that this also will not spit out the first directory name.

The second one never changes - it just continually checks to see if the value in (ent) is null. So it will ONLY spit out the name of the first directory, and nothing else, and will continue to do so forever.

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion might come from a mistaken interpretation of `readdir`. You might be thinking that `readdir` returns the same thing (the "directory" or a "listing" of the directory) each time—hence your puzzlement as to why there's a difference in the two codes, when apparently (to you) the state of the program hasn't changed. However, that interpretation of `readdir` is false! Each invocation of `readdir` returns a pointer to the *next* file in the directory, because the system "remembers" where you left off after each call. When all files have been traversed, then `readdir` finally returns `NULL`, at which point the `while` condition fails and exits.

Answer (score 0):

In this piece of code

```
while((ent) != NULL){
    cout << ent->d_name;
}
```

the variable `ent` is never changed, so once you enter the while, you are trapped there.

in this peice of code

```
while((ent = readdir (directory)) != NULL){
    cout << ent->d_name;
}
```

the variable `ent` is changed each time before the while condition is checked, so you have a chance to come to an end.

This is the correct way how to traverse a directory tree, `readdir` is called recursively.